# CakePHP 2.x first login with hash password no users in DB

Tags: php, database, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.3

I have already check and when I create users and passwords and then I try to login and is successful, however if for example I install on other device my project and set up my DB I enter to my system how can I access for first time if I dont have users created?

1) I tried to create user and password on my database but it cant recognize the password due to hashing methods.

How can i access for the first time and then create users as normal?

My login access controller:

```
    public function login() {

    //if already logged-in, redirect
    if($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));        
    }

    // if we get the post information, try to authenticate
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Bienvenido, '. $this->Auth->user('username')));
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Usuario o password invalidos'));
        }

    } 
    $this->layout = 'login';                                
}
```

appcontroller:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    //public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');
public $components = array(
    //'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => 'Controller',
        'actionPath' => 'controllers/',
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authError' => 'You must be logged in to view this page.',
            'loginError' => 'Invalid Username or Password entered, please try again.'
    ),
    );

// only allow the login controllers only
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('login','view','index','logout','getData');
}

public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // Here is where we should verify the role and give access based on role
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'adm') {
        return true;
    }     

    if (in_array($this->action, array('add','getData','getDataArticulos','addDetFac','descargar','getNit'))) {

         if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'vend')
            return true; 
         else 
            return $this->Session->setFlash(__('Acceso denegado.'), 'error');
    }

    return  $this->Session->setFlash(__('Acceso denegado.'), 'error');
}
```

}

Comment: Is all of that just about creating a new default user in a new instance of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first allow add method.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('login','view','index','logout','getData','add');
}
```

Then create a user, write in your browser URL your_project_path/users/add

After add 1st user remove add from Auth allow.